# LVL license server always returns UNLICENSED

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am always getting UNLICENSED when testing my first/new android app.

I have my Play and Google-Developer (with "Apps Marketplace API") accounts linked

I'm using the Play Base64-encoded RSA in my app.   package names match (app and console).

In Play console i have my ID as a tester, LICENSED reply is set.

perhaps not necessary but in APK I :  1) uploaded my apk to Alpha, 2) set up a google group (manage list of testers) and I'm a member.  This is just for dist to other registered devs, correct?

app is using "ServerManagedPolicy".  I made up a random "salt" -- is that OK or does that need to be registered somewhere(?) in Play Console?

On my device i verified that the "Play Store" app is using the same account as that for the test account.

I see logcat entries to bind, send, receive LVL.  I get "UNLICENSED" (3) message every time.

Any ideas?  Are there any LVL server logs that I can access & view that might hint at the problem?  Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making your own salt should be ok.  meaning, it works for others.  in fact, even though the docs don't say it, you should use a different salt than the example given in the docs. it would be very unwise for everyone to use the same salt as in the docs.

no ideas.  but, i asked the same question and got a negative vote.  but, no answers or suggestions.  it is a new feature and barely documented.  my guess it has bugs that have been unaddressed yet.